Custom PrimeVue CSS
I'm using Vue3 and for theming I'm using Primevue which I find very pleasing but I came across a problem and I didn't find a way yet to solve it.
I have an accordion and I'm simply trying to put the toggle Icon on the left rather than the default right. How to achieve that ?
Playground

That playground is nice, but it's not the right way to share your code on Stack Overflow. See: How do I ask a good question? Notice that it says: "but also copy the code into the question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.". Stack Overflow is meant to be a repository of questions and answers.

Oh right ! I wasn't aware of this, thank you !

Found the solution !
<template>
  <ThemeSwitcher />
  <div class="card">
    <Panel
      header="Header"
      toggleable
      :pt="{
        header: (options) => ({
          id: 'myPanelHeader',
          style: {
            'user-select': 'none',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'start', // HERE
            flexDirection: 'row-reverse', // AND HERE
          },
          class: [
            'border-primary',
            {
              'bg-primary text-primary-contrast': options.state.d_collapsed,
              'text-primary bg-primary-contrast': !options.state.d_collapsed,
            },
          ],
        }),
        content: { class: 'border-primary text-lg text-primary-700' },
        title: 'text-xl', // OR { class: 'text-xl' }
        toggler: () =>
          'bg-primary text-primary-contrast hover:text-primary hover:bg-primary-contrast', // OR { class: 'bg-primary text-primary-contrast hover:text-primary hover:bg-primary-contrast' }
      }"
    >
      <p class="m-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
        velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
        occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
        mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </Panel>
  </div>
</template>

